# Resume file downloaded in java is corrupted

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, download, resume

I have implemented the resume downloading after a crash or
interrupt, I successfully did that but now i am getting a corrupted
file. Can anyone please help me sorting out this problem.

```
URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conection.setDoInput(true);
            conection.setDoOutput(true);
            if (downloadstatus) {
                file = new File(DESTINATION_PATH + f_url[1] + EXTEN);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    downloaded = (int) file.length();
                    conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");
                } else {
                    conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
                }
                lenghtOfFile= conection.getContentLength();

                conection.connect();

                input = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream());
                output=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH + f_url[1] + EXTEN): new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH + f_url[1] + EXTEN,true);
                bout = new BufferedOutputStream(output, 1024);
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int x = 0;
                long total = 0;
                while ((x = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                    total += x;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    bout.write(data, 0, x);
                    downloaded += x;

                }
```

Comment: What is the size of final download , what is expected size?

Comment: It will be approx 1GB of size.

Comment: Well , and what is the size of your download? Compared to expected , you sayd its corrupted , something is missing  right? What have you tryed to debug this? Are you off by 1 byte or ?

Comment: I am off to approx 1024 bytes.